# Is it possible to set the scaleImage property with dynamic expression?

Tags: image, jasper-reports

The `scaleImage="RetainShape"` works correctly for a larger image but for a smaller image, it enlarges(stretches, hampering the image quality) it as per either by width or height of the report element .

```
<image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
    <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="534" height="300"
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{originalImage}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Can we set the `scaleImage` property Dynamically? If (image is large)  `scaleImage="RetainShape"` else `scaleImage="Clip"`

Comment: Did you try to set property with conditional style? The `net.sf.jasperreports.style.scaleImage` is present at [net.sf.jasperreports.style.{style_property_suffix}](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.style.{style_property_suffix}) list

Comment: Will give it a try . Thanks for the reply  @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are searching answers for similar scenarios...
So as Alex suggested, I created a conditional style and applied it to the image tag

```
<style name="scaleImageStyle" hImageAlign="Center" vImageAlign="Middle">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{originalImage}.getHeight(null) <=300]]></conditionExpression>
        <style scaleImage="Clip"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{originalImage}.getHeight(null) >300]]></conditionExpression>
        <style scaleImage="RetainShape"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>

<image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
            <reportElement style="scaleImageStyle" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="535" height="300" uuid="d813ec39-6f47-4361-9d82-c312924c2ba0"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{originalImage}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```